# Qual a origem do sinal til (~)?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, acentuação

Recentemente, vi em um fórum que a origem do sinal **til** (**~**) seria um *N* no final de algumas palavras e que foi mudando com o tempo, porém não encontrei algo que corroborasse com a explicação.

**Explicação no fórum**

> Em Latim, maçã é mattiana, mas o pessoal de Portugal e Espanha provavelmente escrevia maꝢana porque esses dois *Ts* tinham o mesmo som daquele *Ꝣ* (vou chamar de Z estranho e a origem desse Z estranho é outra história longa). Com o passar do tempo, aquele Z estranho virou o nosso Ç em Portugal e ficou igual ao Z normal na Espanha. O jeito de falar maꝢana também mudou. Em Portugal, o Z estranho ficou com som de S e paramos de falar o A do final então ficou maçan, só que o pessoal da época era criativo e colocava o N em cima do A o que deu origem ao til em maçã (sim o til era um N antigamente). Já na Espanha, o Z estranho ficou com som de Z e, por balaca mesmo, sem muita lógica, eles acabaram falando um N depois do MA ficando manzana.

Comment: A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Abbreviation) diz o mesmo, infelizmente sem fontes: "it was used to make abbreviations in medieval Latin documents. When an ⟨n⟩ or ⟨m⟩ followed a vowel, it was often omitted, and a tilde (physically, a small ⟨N⟩) was placed over the preceding vowel to indicate the missing letter; this is the origin of the use of tilde to indicate nasalization [...] The practice [...] continued in printed books in French as a means of reducing text length until the 17th century. It was also used in Portuguese and Spanish."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em linhas gerais a descrição está correta.

Uma referência histórica (indicada pelo Valdeir Psr) é *A Orthographia da Lingoa Portvgvesa* (1576) de Duarte Nunes de Leão ([Biblioteca Nacional](https://purl.pt/15), [Google Books](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=PhA8AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false)) que, como editado no [livro](http://hdl.handle.net/10348/9781) de Assunção et al., descreve na página 24:

> TIL não he letra, mas hũa linha & abbreuiatura, que se põe sobre as dições, com que supprimos muitas letras. [...] como, bispo,
> apostolo, tempo, bp̃o, aplõ, tp̃o. Mas o mais frequente vso desta abbreuiatura, he seruir de .m.n.

O próprio texto desse livro provê diversos exemplos do til como abreviação de "m" ou "n":

> corrõpem, hũa ["uma"], cõ, tẽpo, algũa, diphthõgo, quãdo, dizẽdo, quẽ ["quem"]

entre muitos outros.

Outra referência (citada nessa [postagem](https://shadycharacters.co.uk/2015/03/miscellany-60-tilde/)) é o livro *Nasal Vowel Evolution in Romance* (1999) de Rodney Sampson da [Oxford University Press](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/nasal-vowel-evolution-in-romance-9780198238485?cc=de&lang=en&) ([Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?redir_esc=y&id=EVjCnKuW_l0C&q=tilde#v=snippet&q=tilde&f=false)), que afirma (pg. 40):

> The tilde derives from a superscript N placed over the preceding letter symbol. Subsequently, it was also sometimes used as an abbreviatory device to represent non-nasal sounds. For example <**q̃**> is found in texts from various areas to represent *que*.

Em tradução livre:

> O til deriva de um N sobrescrito colocado sobre a letra precedente. Mais tarde, por vezes ele também foi usado como um mecanismo abreviatório para representar sons não nasais. Por exemplo, encontra-se que <**q̃**> representa *que* em textos de várias áreas.

Maiores detalhes e indícios presentes no restante do texto incluem:

> the widespread practice among medieval scribes of using a tilde '~' over a vowel is ambiguous as to levels of vowel nasality. Often the tilde served as no more than a conventional abbreviation for indicating  the presence of a following nasal consonant, this being its function in medieval Latin texts where its use first developed. However, in certain Romance areas, scribes began to use the tilde as a sign of vowel nasality too. This ambiguity means that it is by no means self-evident what value the tilde has in a particular text
> [...]
> The medieval practice of using the tilde over a vowel as an abbreviatory device to indicate a following nasal consonant was continued in printed work also. In Spanish, the grammar by Nebrija appearing in 1492 contains forms such as <**perderiã**, **pronũciaciõ**>, and in France, Henri Estienne's *Traicté de la conformité du langage François avec le Grec* (published in Paris in 1565) likewise contains forms such as <**lãgue**, **quãd**, **cõdamneriõs**>, where in this instance the tilde happens to coincide with the presence of vowel nasality. The use of the tilde is found in some printed works into the seventeenth century.

Em tradução livre:

> A prática difundida entre escribas medievais de usar o til '~' sobre uma vogal é ambígua com relação à nasalidade vocálica. Frequentemente o til servia apenas como uma abreviação comum indicando a presença de uma consoante nasal a seguir, tal como nos textos medievais em latim em que o til originalmente surgiu. Contudo, em algumas áreas românicas, escribas começaram a usar o til também como um sinal de nasalidade. Esta ambiguidade significa que o valor do til num determinado texto não é de forma alguma autoevidente.
> [...]
> A prática medieval de usar o til sobre uma vogal como um mecanismo abreviatório para indicar uma consoante nasal subsequente continuou também em trabalhos impressos. Em espanhol, a gramática de Nebrija de 1492 contém formas como <**perderiã**, **pronũciaciõ**>, e, na França, o *Traicté de la conformité du langage François avec le Grec* (publicada em Paris em 1565) de Henri Estienne, similarmente contém formas tais como <**lãgue**, **quãd**, **cõdamneriõs**>, em que nesse caso o til por acaso coincide com a presença de nasalidade vocal. O [este?] uso do til é encontrado em trabalhos impressos até o séc. XVII.

Comment: Minha cabeça explodiu com a confirmação. Nunca imaginei a origem.  Procurei noutros lugares e encontrei mais fontes: [Orthographia da Lingoa Portuguesa (1576)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=PhA8AAAAcAAJ&newbks=0&dq=origem%20do%20sinal%20til&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA24&source=bookclip&ci=90%2C310%2C277%2C174#v=onepage&q&f=false) e [Ortografia e origem da língua portuguesa (1983)](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Ortografia_e_origem_da_l%C3%ADngua_portugues/YscdAQAAIAAJ?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=0&bsq=origem%20do%20sinal%20til)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Ótima referência, a primeira, vou tentar incluí-la depois na resposta; à segunda por alguma razão não tenho acesso.

Comment: "vso" com v em vez de u, "seruir" com u em vez de v... grisei-me :D

Comment: Com a primeira citação, ficou mesmo uma resposta fenomenal... obrigado, adorei!

Comment: @ANeves Mérito total do Valdeir. Sobre os us e vs, acho divertido. :)